No sound on Debian virtual machine
I installed Debian and gnome using Virtual Box. Everything is working fine except the sound. It's not totally absent though, for instance if i play a video it will make sound for a second and then stop, sometimes it will work again for another second and then stop again.
System:
  Host: debian Kernel: 6.1.0-21-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc
    v: 12.2.0 Desktop: GNOME v: 43.9 tk: GTK v: 3.24.38 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3
    Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Machine:
  Type: Virtualbox System: innotek GmbH product: VirtualBox v: 1.2
    serial: <superuser required> Chassis: Oracle Corporation type: 1
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Oracle model: VirtualBox v: 1.2 serial: <superuser required>
    BIOS: innotek GmbH v: VirtualBox date: 12/01/2006
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 50.0 Wh (100.0%) condition: 50.0/50.0 Wh (100.0%)
    volts: 10.0 min: 10.0 model: innotek 1 serial: N/A status: full
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i7-9750H bits: 64 type: MCP
    arch: Coffee Lake rev: A cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 48 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2598 min/max: N/A cores: 1: 2598 2: 2598 3: 2598 4: 2598
    bogomips: 20781
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3
Graphics:
  Device-1: VMware SVGA II Adapter driver: vmwgfx v: 2.20.0.0 ports:
    active: Virtual-1 empty: Virtual-2, Virtual-3, Virtual-4, Virtual-5,
    Virtual-6, Virtual-7, Virtual-8 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 15ad:0405
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.9 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: dri: swrast gpu: vmwgfx display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: Virtual-1 mapped: XWAYLAND0 res: 1920x1080 size: N/A
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6 256 bits)
    direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801AA AC97 Audio driver: snd_intel8x0 v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:05.0 chip-ID: 8086:2415
  API: ALSA v: k6.1.0-21-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet driver: e1000 v: kernel port: d020
    bus-ID: 00:03.0 chip-ID: 8086:100e
  IF: enp0s3 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 08:00:27:e1:29:bb
  Device-2: Intel 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI type: network bridge
    driver: piix4_smbus v: N/A port: N/A bus-ID: 00:07.0 chip-ID: 8086:7113
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 30 GiB used: 5.77 GiB (19.2%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: VirtualBox model: VBOX HARDDISK size: 30 GiB
    speed: 3.0 Gb/s serial: VB87e7b0a9-c41072fe
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 28.42 GiB used: 5.77 GiB (20.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 975 MiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/sda5
Sensors:
  Src: lm-sensors+/sys Message: No sensor data found using /sys/class/hwmon
    or lm-sensors.
Info:
  Processes: 189 Uptime: 5m Memory: 3.73 GiB used: 1.17 GiB (31.4%)
  Init: systemd v: 252 target: graphical (5) default: graphical Compilers: N/A
  Packages: pm: dpkg pkgs: 1611 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15
  running-in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.3.26


Guest additions are not required for sound in VB to work. They are for 1) shared folders 2) time keeping 3) GPU 4) clipboard. That's it.

Perhaps you should try changing the VM's audio settings to "Intel HD audio" instead of the (literally last century's) "AC97".

I tried that already but it is still not working.

Try to change Host Audio Driver to something different. And make sure audio on your host is working.
